# Windows installation blue screen (any windows version)

Tags: windows, memory, bsod, windows-installation

I'm having troubles imstalling any version of windows. It started when I acccedentaly powered off my pc while it was updating (it was in windows 10) and since then I can not install any windows version. It crashes with BSD like 'irql_not_less_or_equal' or 'PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA'. I've tried to boot installation from dvd (win 7 and win 8) and from usb (win 8 and win 10) and one time tried win XP from cd and sometimes it hangs and some times it shows BSD. In the internet they say it's problem with RAM but RAM was OK before I powered off my PC while it was updating. Is really RAM broken? I've tried to test ram with memory management tool which is shipped with win XP disk. It passed ~10 tests (then I cancelled it), there was no errors. I created an ubuntu usb and run Memtest from it - there was no error either. Currently I can not buy new RAM. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: If you can also mention the error code of the BSD. It's formatted like this : 0x00000001 (ex.) and look up that code through google and you might find solution.
Also try this page here :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff560129(v=vs.85).aspx See if this solves it.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any other data on the drive you're trying to install too? If not and if you have access to another computer, any windows OS, connect the drive to that computer and delete all partitions. The leave the drive void, no partitions, and try installing again. Anytime I've had a BOSD during an install it's because windows didn't like something in the drives partition table.